# Linux auth to wireless before LDAP/AD logon?

Tags: linux, authentication, ldap, wifi, login

Is it possible, on a linux machine configured for AD or LDAP logon, when the user logs on, to use that username and password to connect to a WPA enterprise wifi connection, which would then allow the AD/LDAP logon to go ahead?

Answer (score 0):

Sort of, though it depends how your Linux machine is configured.  If it allows cached credentials, then the intial login while the machine is not connected to the network (I am assuming this is the scenario) should be sucessful.  Then the wireless can connect.  After this you are logged into the PC, and the credentials are used to access domain resources.  Not exactly what you asked, but effectively the same.  If the AD credentials had expired, after logging on you would likely need to re-authenticate when accessing a domain resource.

Comment: In particular, I would like to hook into the username and password that the user enters on logon, and pass this to the wpa supplicant to use for the wireless logon.

Comment: So you need to make sure that your access points are authenticating against Active Directory, most likely using 802.11x.  I am sure there is a way of having WPA supplicant use this with the logged in users credentials, but that is where my knowledge runs out unfortunately.  Hope this is at least getting you somewhere closer to a solution.